# Need help with orignal samsung touchwiz ROM Recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, clockworkmod-recovery, device-firmware

Hi a while back i rooted my S3 Neo I9301I and installed a couple of ROMS based on android 4.4.2/4.4.4 and then i would restore the Nandroid backup i had made of the samsung's touchwiz ROM (The one which came with the phone when i bought it TouchWiz 4.4.2 Kitkat)

Then i thought i'd go ahead and try the unofficial Cyanogenmod 12 by Rox with 5.0 GAPPS, didnt like the performance, but this time when i restored my nandroid, after booting up the phone there's a black screen and all apps crash with the usual error message e.g. "Unfortunately settings has stopped". I've now lost the touchWiz Backup. Same situation even after i flashed GAPPS 4.4.x, so i reinstalled CM12 and GAPPS 5.0 and now im stuck with it.

TLDR:

**I've lost the touchWiz nandroid backup.**

A) **Anyway i can get back the orignal Samsung TouchWiz 4.4.2 ROM?**

B) **Im looking into upgrading the firmware. Will the latest firmware include Samsung's TouchWiz?**

If i've said anything technically incorrect, bare with me please im not THAT big of a tech wiz :D

Phone Specs:
Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo I9301I, 16GB, I9301IXXUANH1 (Single Sim Variant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in response to you question :

- **Part A**

  - yes you can go back to touchwizz any time you want by flashing an officiel firmware or by flashing a custom rom based on a stock rom.
- **part B**

  - grab a firmware from [this page](http://www.mrcrab.net/stockrom/gt-i9301i.html)
  - grab Odin flashing tool from [here](http://odindownload.com/)
  - install samsung drivers [(here)](http://androidxda.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers)
  - unzip the firmware you just download you will get one file with .tar or .tar.md5.
  - Now lets make sure you do a fresh install ,boot to recovery and do a full wipe don't reboot the system power off the device after the full wipe and boot to download mod.
  - unzip odin archive and execute Odin executable file.
  - plug your device to your PC via USB cable (the device must be in download mod)
  - An “Added!!” massage will appear in Odin’s message box. If you don’t get the same then you should try another USB port (try USB port located in back in your desktop PC). If that too don’t work then you should reinstall the driver. If you successfully see the “Added!!” message in Odin then you are ready to go in next step. You should also see COM port with a number in Yellow if you successfully added your device.
  - Click the AP Button, and select that .tar.md5 file
  - In Odin window, make sure only Auto Reboot and F. Reset Time checkboxes are selected.
  - hit the START button to begin the flashing process ,when the process is working don't open other applications on you PC don't touch the PC or the usb cable or the phone
  - Once flashing completed, your Galaxy S3 Neo GT-I9301I will restart and soon you will see a PASS message with green background in the left-most box at the very top of the Odin. You can now unplug the USB cable to disconnect your device from computer.